# android NullPointerException on checking null value

Tags: android, string, null

I am getting some data from server and setting the values in a getter and setter class. When the values seems to be null i am getting following values in my getter setter class

```
Tag [seatNo=null, Value=null, player1=null, player2=null, player3=null, player4=null, player5=null ]
```

The above value is been printed in Logcat

after getting above values i am checking an if condition because of which the app crashes

```
if (bet.getSeatNo() != null || !bet.getSeatNo().isEmpty() || !bet.getSeatNo().equals("null"))
{

}
```

how to check it is null or not ?

Comment: `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bet.getSeatNo()))`

Comment: can you please post the error stack trace

Comment: you are getting a NPE because your `bet` object is null.
What you are trying to do here is ,retrieving a value on a null object resulting in a NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if the value is not empty.

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bet.getSeatNo())){
//Check your condition here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this way:

```
    if (bet.getSeatNo() != null)
    {
        if(!bet.getSeatNo().isEmpty() && !bet.getSeatNo().equals("null"))
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before checking the field empty/null, check whether "bet" object is null or not.
NullPointerException occurs while accessing fields of null object.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (bet.getSeatNo() != null || !bet.getSeatNo().isEmpty() || !bet.getSeatNo().equals("null"))
> ```

If `bet.getSeatNo() != null` is `false`, only then the second `!bet.getSeatNo().isEmpty()` is evaluated. But since the first only evaluates to `false` if `getSeatNo()` returns `null`, the second conditional must NPE. Notice the problem?

Use `&&` instead of `||` so that the short-circuiting stops on first `false` and not on the first `true`.